# How can I change the hover and focus state simlutaneously for both the svg and text in a form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I customized my radio buttons to have the smiley svgs with a text underneath. Now, I want both my svg and text to change the opacity when hovered and checked together. It only works for the svgs but for the text, only the hover state is working and not the focus or active state. How can I achieve this?

```css
svg {
  fill: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  height: 3.6rem;
  width: 3.6rem;
  margin: 0.2rem;
}

input[class="no-barrier"]+svg,
.green {
  fill: rgb(0, 204, 79);
  opacity: 0.25;
  color: rgb(0, 204, 79);
}

input[class="few-barriers"]+svg,
.yellow {
  fill: rgb(232, 214, 0);
  opacity: 0.25;
  color: rgb(232, 214, 0);
}

input[class="moderate-barriers"]+svg,
.orange {
  fill: rgb(229, 132, 0);
  opacity: 0.25;
  color: rgb(229, 132, 0);
}

input[class="extreme-barriers"]+svg,
.red {
  fill: rgb(239, 42, 16);
  opacity: 0.25;
  color: rgb(239, 42, 16);
}

input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="radio"]+svg+.green {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

input+svg,
span {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* .no-barrier:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 204, 79);
    fill: rgb(0, 204, 79);
} */

input[class="no-barrier"]:hover+svg,
input[class="no-barrier"]:checked+svg,
input[class="no-barrier"]:focus+svg,
.green:hover,
.green:checked,
.green:focus,
active-green:hover,
active-green:checked,
active-green:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}

.active.green {
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(0, 204, 79);
}

.active.yellow {
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(0, 204, 79);
}

.active.orange {
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(0, 204, 79);
}

.active.red {
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(0, 204, 79);
}

input[class="few-barriers"]:hover+svg,
input[class="few-barriers"]:checked+svg,
input[class="few-barriers"]:focus+svg,
span.yellow:hover,
span.yellow:checked,
span.yellow:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}

input[class="moderate-barriers"]:hover+svg,
input[class="moderate-barriers"]:checked+svg,
input[class="moderate-barriers"]:focus+svg,
span.orange:hover,
span.orange:checked,
span.orange:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}

input[class="extreme-barriers"]:hover+svg,
input[class="extreme-barriers"]:checked+svg,
input[class="extreme-barriers"]:focus+svg,
span.red:hover,
span.red:checked,
span.red:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}

span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#contact-method-label label,
#barrier-level-label label,
#employer-terminating label,
#accessibility-experience-label label,
#further-clarification-label label {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.form-errors li {
  color: #cf2334;
}

.captchaError {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #cf2334;
  font-size: 16px;
}

form {
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.form-check {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.form-row {
  display: flex;
}

div:hover>*,
div:focus>* {
  color: pink
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="barrier-level-label">Rate the level of barrier *</label>
  <div class="form-row" id="barrier-level-label">
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="no-barrier">
                    <input type="radio" name="barrier-level" class="no-barrier" id="no-barrier" value="1 - no-barrier"/>
                   <div> <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12,17.5C14.33,17.5 16.3,16.04 17.11,14H6.89C7.69,16.04 9.67,17.5 12,17.5M8.5,11A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 10,9.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 8.5,8A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 7,9.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 8.5,11M15.5,11A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 17,9.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 15.5,8A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 14,9.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 15.5,11M12,20A8,8 0 0,1 4,12A8,8 0 0,1 12,4A8,8 0 0,1 20,12A8,8 0 0,1 12,20M12,2C6.47,2 2,6.5 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z" /></svg>
                     <span class="green">1 - no barrier</span></div></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="few-barriers">
                    <input type="radio" name="barrier-level" class="few-barriers" id="few-barriers" value="2 - few-barriers"  />
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M20,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,4A8,8 0 0,0 4,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,20A8,8 0 0,0 20,12M22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12M10,9.5C10,10.3 9.3,11 8.5,11C7.7,11 7,10.3 7,9.5C7,8.7 7.7,8 8.5,8C9.3,8 10,8.7 10,9.5M17,9.5C17,10.3 16.3,11 15.5,11C14.7,11 14,10.3 14,9.5C14,8.7 14.7,8 15.5,8C16.3,8 17,8.7 17,9.5M12,17.23C10.25,17.23 8.71,16.5 7.81,15.42L9.23,14C9.68,14.72 10.75,15.23 12,15.23C13.25,15.23 14.32,14.72 14.77,14L16.19,15.42C15.29,16.5 13.75,17.23 12,17.23Z" /></svg>
                    <span class="yellow">2 - few barriers</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a link for the code pen: https://codepen.io/jagriti_130501/pen/gOvQOQg

How can I achieve the same with minimum of either css/html/js code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all your rules for the `span` elements are checking if *that* element is `checked`, e.g. `span.yellow:checked`, not if the input itself is checked with a following span.

You can also easily reduce the amount of CSS since you don't have to know what color the span is, since all check boxes do the same thing: change opacity. You can use the `~` sibling selector instead.

Also, you had an extra `<div>` wrapping the svg and span in the first label.

```css
svg {
  fill: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  height: 3.6rem;
  width: 3.6rem;
  margin: 0.2rem;
}

input[class="no-barrier"]+svg,
.green {
  fill: rgb(0, 204, 79);
  opacity: 0.25;
  color: rgb(0, 204, 79);
}

input[class="few-barriers"]+svg,
.yellow {
  fill: rgb(232, 214, 0);
  opacity: 0.25;
  color: rgb(232, 214, 0);
}

input[class="moderate-barriers"]+svg,
.orange {
  fill: rgb(229, 132, 0);
  opacity: 0.25;
  color: rgb(229, 132, 0);
}

input[class="extreme-barriers"]+svg,
.red {
  fill: rgb(239, 42, 16);
  opacity: 0.25;
  color: rgb(239, 42, 16);
}

input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="radio"]+svg+.green {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

input+svg,
span {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Use the ~ general sibling selector for the spans */

input[type="radio"]:hover+svg,
input[type="radio"]:checked+svg,
input[type="radio"]:focus+svg,
input[type="radio"]:hover~span,
input[type="radio"]:checked~span,
input[type="radio"]:focus~span {
  opacity: 1;
}

.active.green {
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(0, 204, 79);
}

.active.yellow {
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(0, 204, 79);
}

.active.orange {
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(0, 204, 79);
}

.active.red {
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(0, 204, 79);
}

span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#contact-method-label label,
#barrier-level-label label,
#employer-terminating label,
#accessibility-experience-label label,
#further-clarification-label label {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.form-errors li {
  color: #cf2334;
}

.captchaError {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #cf2334;
  font-size: 16px;
}

form {
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.form-check {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.form-row {
  display: flex;
}

div:hover>*,
div:focus>* {
  color: pink
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="barrier-level-label">Rate the level of barrier *</label>
  <div class="form-row" id="barrier-level-label">
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="no-barrier">
                    <input type="radio" name="barrier-level" class="no-barrier" id="no-barrier" value="1 - no-barrier"/>
                   <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12,17.5C14.33,17.5 16.3,16.04 17.11,14H6.89C7.69,16.04 9.67,17.5 12,17.5M8.5,11A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 10,9.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 8.5,8A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 7,9.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 8.5,11M15.5,11A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 17,9.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 15.5,8A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 14,9.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 15.5,11M12,20A8,8 0 0,1 4,12A8,8 0 0,1 12,4A8,8 0 0,1 20,12A8,8 0 0,1 12,20M12,2C6.47,2 2,6.5 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z" /></svg>
                     <span class="green">1 - no barrier</span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="few-barriers">
                    <input type="radio" name="barrier-level" class="few-barriers" id="few-barriers" value="2 - few-barriers"  />
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M20,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,4A8,8 0 0,0 4,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,20A8,8 0 0,0 20,12M22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12M10,9.5C10,10.3 9.3,11 8.5,11C7.7,11 7,10.3 7,9.5C7,8.7 7.7,8 8.5,8C9.3,8 10,8.7 10,9.5M17,9.5C17,10.3 16.3,11 15.5,11C14.7,11 14,10.3 14,9.5C14,8.7 14.7,8 15.5,8C16.3,8 17,8.7 17,9.5M12,17.23C10.25,17.23 8.71,16.5 7.81,15.42L9.23,14C9.68,14.72 10.75,15.23 12,15.23C13.25,15.23 14.32,14.72 14.77,14L16.19,15.42C15.29,16.5 13.75,17.23 12,17.23Z" /></svg>
                    <span class="yellow">2 - few barriers</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```